# I am trying to call super parametersised constructor but it throws an error

Tags: java

i am trying to call super class paramertrised consrtuctor from the
        derived class

```
 class SC
    {
        SC()
        {
            System.out.println("SC.......DC");
        }
        SC(int x)
        {
            System.out.println("SC........PC");
        }
    }
  class SS
    {
        SS()
        {
            super(10);
            System.out.println("SS.......DC");
        }
        SS(int x)
        {
            this();
            System.out.println("SS........PC");
        }
    }
   public class OpConstructor {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SS do1=new SS(10);  }

    }
```

Comment: What error does it give you

Comment: Did you intend SS to extend SC?

Comment: `class SS` -> `class SS extends SC`.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
class SS
```

which means `SS` is a top-level class. It has no superclass (other than Object), so you don't call a superclass constructor. To give it a superclass, you add `extends`. For instance, to have it extend `SC`:

```
class SS extends SC
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you missed extending the class SC by SS. This is how your classes should look like.

OpConstructor:

```
public class OpConstructor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SS do1 = new SS(10);
    }

}
```

SS and SC class:

```
public class SC {
    SC() {
        System.out.println("SC.......DC");
    }

    SC(int x) {
        System.out.println("SC........PC");
    }
}

class SS extends SC {
    SS() {
        super(10);
        System.out.println("SS.......DC");
    }

    SS(int x) {
        this();
        System.out.println("SS........PC");
    }
}
```